# Failed to use tidyr function "spread"

Tags: r

I had to re-install RStudio on my machine, and now I encounter an error when using the "spread" function in "tidyr". I can use "stringr" though. Here is the error message.

Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘tidyr’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):
namespace ‘dplyr’ 0.8.0.1 is already loaded, but >= 0.8.2 is required
In addition: Warning message:
package ‘tidyr’ was built under R version 3.6.3

Error in spread(., solution, sum_fund) : could not find function "spread"

Comment: You have an older version (`namespace ‘dplyr’ 0.8.0.1 is already loaded, but >= 0.8.2`).  Please consider to update R and the packages

Comment: Thanks. My RStudio is in the App "Ananconda". How do I get a newer version in Anaconda?